# NodeGit how to get last commit id of another branch?

Tags: node.js, nodegit, node-github

I have two branches checked out of my system Master and Dev.

My Working directory is Master from Master I want to push/merge file to dev after knowing the difference.

For say in Master I am working abc.txt file and I want to check the difference between the file present in dev with master.
How can I do it?

**Getting this error**

> error while pushing == Error: no reference found for shorthand 'dev'
>   (node:93479) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: no reference found for shorthand
>   'dev'

**Code**

```
differenceCommit(fileName,branchName) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
            let repo,
                changes;
            open("./master")
                .then(function (repoResult) {
                    repo = repoResult;
                    return repo;
                })
                .then(function (commitId) {
                    return repo.getBranchCommit("dev");
                })
                ///Difference Before Push
                .then(function (commit) {
                    return commit.getDiffWithOptions("dev");
                })
                .then(function (diffList) {
                    console.log("************************");
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `origin/` to the name of the branch:

```
differenceCommit(fileName,branchName) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
            let repo,
                changes;
            open("./master")
                .then(function (repoResult) {
                    repo = repoResult;
                    return repo;
                })
                .then(function (commitId) {
                    return repo.getBranchCommit("origin/dev");
                })
                ///Difference Before Push
                .then(function (commit) {
                    return commit.getDiffWithOptions("origin/dev");
                })
                .then(function (diffList) {
                    console.log("************************");
                });
    }
```

Comment: I am still not able to get latest changes that i am making

Comment: No i am not getting the error now. Not getting the comparision with the latest file

Comment: I have different checkout folder for these 2 branches